# How could I detect if there is a key press support in the browser for arrow keys?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, keypress, arrow-keys

I am working on a web game (http://szarada.net/wyscigi/) for crossword solvers (Polish language). One of features I am planning to introduce is to support moving a cursor on a crossword diagram using arrow keys. To provide even more user experience, I would like to support key press event (not key down or key up) for arrow keys wherever possible (in order to let the user move the cursor by multiple fields with long key press).

What I was able to realise by examining several Internet resources (including multiple StackOverflow entries) is that only some browsers do support the key press for arrow keys.

Here comes my question -- how to detect whether the browser supports the feature of firing a key press event for arrow key? I was thinking about just detecting a browser (plus browser version), but feature based solution would obviously be more scalable. I did not find anything useful in e.g. the Modernizr.

I am using jQuery, so that jQuery-based advice would be most beneficial for me.

Comment: Play around [**here**](http://unixpapa.com/js/testkey.html) in a couple browsers, you may decide if you really only want to look at _keypress_ then you'll have to use _NumPad_ keys (and hence the other number keys will also have the same result)

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript key handling and browser compatibility](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3476000/javascript-key-handling-and-browser-compatibility)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, keyDown is the event you are looking for. It is being fired repeatedly if the user keeps pressing the key.

So, don't use KeyPress, use KeyDown instead, and you'll be fine in all browsers.

Comment: Thank you, pryma! I changed my code and have listened to the key down event. Everything works perfectly under Chrome, FF, IE, Opera. I did not, however, receive answer to my question -- is there any method to detect whether the keypress event supports arrow keys, different than just querying about browser type/version and concluding support basing on that.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is from 2013, but I had to go make my own keypress detection because this didn't help me. Here is the solution I used to get around chrome android not supporting keypress:

```
    $(function () {
        "use strict";
        var keypressDetected = false;

        $('body').on('keypress', function(event) {

               keypressDetected = true;
               alert('key press supported!');

        });

        var e = jQuery.Event("keypress");

        e.which = 50; // The key code that you wish to test for

        $("body").trigger(e);

        if (!keypressDetected) {

           // ... do magic here
        }
    });
```